# profile.getEmail() retrieving two string - one email and another blank

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, google-api-client

I'm signing up users with google in my app and then I'm retrieving there photoUrl, email, and display name.

The problem is that the `profile.getEmail();` is returning/retrieving two strings. One is email and another is blank.

Here's how I'm signing up them:

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView appName;
    ProgressDialog signinProgressDialog;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        signinProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.signupCoordinatorLayout);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.o_auth_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestId()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                    }
                } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    signinProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
                    signinProgressDialog.show();
                    signIn();
                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                    signinProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("firebaseAuthWithGoogle", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("signin_successful", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                        signinProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("signin_unsuccessful", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) SignupActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm retrieving the essentials:

```
public void retrieveUserInfo() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {

                // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
                providerId = profile.getProviderId();

                // UID specific to the provider
                uid = profile.getUid();

                // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                name = profile.getDisplayName();
                email = profile.getEmail();
                photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl().toString();

            }
        }
    }
```

Here, when I placed the email string in a `Toast`, I got 2 toasts, first one displayed the email and second one was blank.

I really don't know what's wrong here.

Please let me know.

Sorry if question seems to be badly formatted. I'm still a beginner here.

Comment: Do you mean firebase is returning a String array? how are you declaring email? have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing code in `retrieveUserInfo()` did the job.

Here's the changed code:

```
public void retrieveUserInfo() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
            providerId = user.getProviderId();

            // UID specific to the provider
            uid = user.getUid();

            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            name = user.getDisplayName();
            email = user.getEmail();
            photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl().toString();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `for()` loop maybe that's causing problem, once it gets the string and other time do not.

Comment: removing for loop did the job for me.